# Problem in Integrating Piksi GPS module into ROS

Tags: gps

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi eveyone,
I am trying to integrate Piksi GPS module into ROS using the  nmea_navsat_driver ROS node. But while running the node ,it receives a sentence with invalid checksum. And I am able to see the list of topics and nodes regarding the node. Can anyone please tel me where I am doing wrong.!
thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200446/problem-in-integrating-piksi-gps-module-into-ros/) by [charan-ram](https://answers.ros.org/users/19829/charan-ram/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-01-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [K7](https://answers.ros.org/users/23630/k7/) on 2015-11-02**:
Did you ever figure this out? I also need to integrate piksi with ros. Would appreciate it if you could tell me how you got this far as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See the answer here:
http://answers.ros.org/question/220347/swiftnavs-piksi/
Paul

---

Originally posted by [PaulBouchier](https://answers.ros.org/users/2700/paulbouchier/) with karma: 300 on 2015-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0